# How to use personal github access token with gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I [mirrored a private repository from Github](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/github_integration.html#connect-with-personal-access-token) to run builds with gitlab runner. My project has private gems hosted on Github and the build is failing with

```
Fetching git@github.com:private/gem.git
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Retrying `git clone 'git@github.com:private/gem.git' "/builds-ci/gitlab/repo/vendor/ruby/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/gem-a356dd016736a58b8b77677e8d7df689f8f43ada" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:private/gem.git' "/builds/gitlab-ci/repo/vendor/ruby/2.4.0/cache/bundler/git/gem-a356dd016736a58b8b77677e8d7df689f8f43ada" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /builds/gitlab-ci/repo has failed.Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I used [personal Github access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) to mirror private repositories from Github to Gitlab. [There is a way](https://depfu.com/blog/2017/08/02/bundler-and-private-dependencies) to use Github access token to clone private gems with bundler without the need to set up SSH keys:

```
export BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=x-access-token:<token>
```

Do I need to create a separate access token and paste it into .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.4.1

variables:
  BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=x-access-token:<token>

...
```

Or I can use the token which I used to mirror repositories from Github? Like this

```
variables:
  BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=x-access-token:$SOME_GITLAB_JOB_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with adding `BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM` to `.gitlab-ci.yml` commiting it to the source code for now:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM=x-access-token:<token>
...
```